# CSS resize heights of images dynamically

Tags: html, css, image, dynamic, resize

I'm working on an image sharing website for one of my computer science classes, and I've been running into trouble when I try to actually display the images to the user. I've let users tag their images, and display images that match one or more tags. However, when I try to display images with different aspect ratios, it looks quite ugly. I want all of the images to have the same height, but allow their widths to change to keep the aspect ratio.

I can solve my problem easily enough if I put a fixed height for each row (e.g. `.row { height: 30vh; }`), but I've been running into issues when I try to have a dynamic height.

Potential soultions I've tried:

- `flex`—`flex` makes the images overlay into each other, and since I don't know the size beforehand, I can't really use `.img{ flex: NUMBER; }`.
- `div`— I wrapped the `img`s in `div`s, and resized the `img` to fit. This is the most common answer I've found, except it doesn't work for the same reason as a plain `img`: I don't know the height beforehand, so I cant set the height of the `div`. I also tried this with `span` and that also didn't work.
- `table`—I tried using a `table`, with a single `tr` tag, and every image written as `<td><img src="..." ></td>`, but this also doesn't work, and isn't exactly what I'm looking for; I don't want a table, as I just have a single column.
- `li`—Each separate list element is on a new line, but I want as many to be on the same line as possible, and there's a bullet point. True, I could remove the bullet point and make the lines wrap, but it still doesn't solve the issue.
- I could theoretically load all the images via JavaScript or PHP (depending on if I make it server- or client-side), find their width, and use that. However, that seems extremely hacky and I want a better solution.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tad37z98/1/) is an example of what it's currently doing. And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z5g7xcjk/) is an example of what I want it to do, without forcing the height in the CSS.

I'd like to do this in just pure CSS + HTML if possible, but I'm not sure it's even possible using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Using width: auto will tell the browser to calculate the width based on proportions.

```
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9h8ey4e/1/) to show you. I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: I tried that. But you still need to set `height: 500px`, which is "hardcoding" the height in. I need it so, in essence, the `height` is the height of the largest image. if I have a 50x10 and a 1000x1000, I'd like it so the 50x10 would become a 1000x200

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code:

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: An explanation to code will make for better answer.